# PHP: Variable declared in an abstract class does not change its value from the cild classes

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to increase the value of a variable which is declared in an abstract class, but every time I increase it from the child classes it keeps assigning 1 instead of increasing its value in every instance.

```
<?php
abstract class sum {
    private $sumResult = 0;
}
class test1 extends sum {
    private $sumResult;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->setSumResult();
    }
    public function setSumResult() {
        $this->sumResult++; //here I try to increase the value of the variable
    }
    public function getSumResult() {
        return $this->sumResult;
    }
}
class test2 extends sum {
    private $sumResult;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->setSumResult();
    }
    public function setSumResult() {
        $this->sumResult++; //here I try to increase the value of the variable
    }
    public function getSumResult() {
        return $this->sumResult;
    }
}
$test1 = new test1();
$test2 = new test2();
echo $test2->getSumResult(); //Here it prints out 1 instead of 2.
?>
```

So, what I want is to increase the value of the variable sumResult in every instance, but it is not working. In the code I wrote it should return 2 instead of 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is not how [object inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) works. There is no relationship between the `test2` and `test1` classes here.

Comment: When you define `$sumResult` in `sum`, setting it as `private` means that derived classes can't use that value. (this is only part of the problem)

Comment: The other part is that it should be declared as *static*.

Comment: The third part is that it shouldn't have to be redefined in subclasses :)

Comment: Congrats! You got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Classes provide a blueprint for the construction of instances. So, each instance has its own set of member variables. Changing a member variable in one instance doesn't change its value for another instance.

Since there's no rule without exception, there are `static` methods and members. These belong to the class, not the instance.

Answer (score 0):

To share a variable across all instances of the classes, you will need to declare it as `static` and here I use `protected` to allow the derived classes to access the same value.  Then each reference to this variable is done using `self::$sumResult`.  You also don't need to declare the variable in each class as this can hide the field in the parent class.

```
abstract class sum {
    protected static $sumResult = 0;
}
class test1 extends sum {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->setSumResult();
    }
    public function setSumResult() {
        self::$sumResult++;
    }
    public function getSumResult() {
        return self::$sumResult;
    }
}
class test2 extends sum {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->setSumResult();
    }
    public function setSumResult() {
        self::$sumResult++;
    }
    public function getSumResult() {
        return self::$sumResult;
    }
}
$test1 = new test1();
$test2 = new test2();
echo $test2->getSumResult(); //Here it prints out 2.
```

Comment: Still weird to have non-static methods deal (only) with static properties, though. All these methods should just be defined within `sum` as static, imho.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has worked! :) I think I would need to learn a bit more about inheritance as I was doing it wrongfully. Have a good day!

Comment: @Jeto, hopefully this is just a proof of concept, especially as the two classes are the same.

Comment: @NigelRen Sure. Posted the alternative in another answer just in case.

Comment: If this has helped, please consider marking it as answered, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative version to what others posted, if that can help. More logical this way imho, considering how static methods/properties work:

```
<?php
abstract class sum
{
  private static $sumResult = 0;

  public function __construct()
  {
    self::setSumResult();
  }

  public static function getSumResult()
  {
    return self::$sumResult;
  }

  private static function setSumResult()
  {
    self::$sumResult++;
  }
}

class test1 extends sum {}

class test2 extends sum {}

$test1 = new test1();
$test2 = new test2();
echo sum::getSumResult();
```